# jquery: post input values to PHP without serializing

Tags: php, jquery

Trying to do very simple thing.

Have too many of these fields:

```
<input name="itempriceqty0" /><input name="itemprice0" /><br />
<input name="itempriceqty1" /><input name="itemprice1" /><br />
<input name="itempriceqty2" /><input name="itemprice2" /><br />
```

etc...

Goal is to get their values in one PHP string of this format: itempriceqty0=itemprice0, itempriceqty1=itemprice1,itempriceqty2=itemprice3,etc...

Serializing with jquery gives a url formatted string, which I need to split many times with PHP to get rid of input names and other &= chars.

```
$.post('test.php', {
  itemprice: $('#itempricefieldswrapper :input').serialize() }, ...
);
```

What is the easiest way to handle it with jquery?

P.S. Googled everywhere. Need help. Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to serialize , why not just post using Ajax , send paremeters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

Give all your input elements to gather a class name, e.g. `qty-input`

Collect the values like this:

```
var values = '';
$('.qty-input').each(function(){
  values = values + this.name + '=' + this.value + ',' ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess each() is the only right way to go.     var itempricevalues = '';
    $('input[name^=itempriceqty]').each(function() {
      var num = $(this).attr('name').replace(/itempriceqty/, '');
      itempricevalues = itempricevalues + this.value + '=' + $('input[name=itemprice'+num+']').val() + ',';
    });

Answer (score 0):

You could look at json:

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)

That post shows how you can read the form values into json and serialize it. You will need a json deserializer library in php of which im sure there's plenty to choose from.

(JSON: json_decode is built in right? Im not a php boi).

Comment: If you have PHP 5.2.0 or greater, there is a built in [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you can use the following:

```
<input type="text" name="foo[]" value="field1" />
<input type="text" name="foo[]" value="field2" />
```

and then, if you do this:

```
var_dump($_POST['foo']);
```

you get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "field1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "field2"
}
```

I'm not sure if that's relevant to what you want but it seems like it might be.